# SSRS Parameter that selects on days of the week within the date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have a report that runs embedded SQL that uses a simple @startDate and @endDate parameter and the variables in a WHERE clause:

```
And DM.FromDateTime Between @startDate AND @endDate
```

What I would like to accomplish is to have an additional parameter that would return only the day of the week the user selected.

For example, if the user chose 3/1/2015 to 3/31/2015 as their date range and selected 'Monday', the report would only populate with data from 3/2, 3/9, 3/16, 3/23, and 3/30.

I know SQL has `datepart (dw)` function, but any advice on how to handle this parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new integer report parameter @DayOfWeek. It's available values are: 
'Sunday' = 1
'Monday' = 2
'Tuesday' = 3
'Wednesday' = 4
'Thursday' = 5
'Friday' = 6
'Saturday' = 7

Then your where clause is simply:

```
And DM.FromDateTime Between @startDate AND @endDate
AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DM.FromDateTime) = @DayOfWeek
```